# Sql lite max dont find column name

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Using:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int max_request_code = 0;
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(" + REQUEST_CODE + ") FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);  
          if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) 
          {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            max_request_code = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(REQUEST_CODE));
          }
          else
              return 0;
          return max_request_code;
```

gives me an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.

on the line containing mCursor.getInt.

This is how i create the table:

```
String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
            +UUID + " TEXT,"+ REQUEST_CODE + " INT,"+ ACTION + " TEXT,"
            + TIME + " TEXT," + DAY + " TEXT," + RECEPIENTS+  " TEXT," +BODY + " TEXT,"  +SUBJECT +
            " TEXT," +STATUS + " TEXT," +REPEAT + " TEXT," +TASK_NAME + " TEXT" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the word AS to assign a column name to the returned MAX value:

```
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(" + REQUEST_CODE + ") AS maxRequest_Code FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;
```

Then get value from cursor:

```
max_request_code = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("maxRequest_Code"));
```

or use:

```
max_request_code = mCursor.getInt(0);
```